# Neo4j Lucene can't create node after a certain limit,why?

Tags: lucene, neo4j

I was trying to insert more than 10k nodes in my local neo4j server.[Mac OS].But after some time it produces run time error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:     /Users/shihabrahman/Development/projects/opt_neo4j_importar/neo4j/data/graph.db/index/lucene/node/146483049887488028/_0.nrm (Too many open files)
at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.refreshSearcher(LuceneDataSource.java:516)
at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.refreshSearcherIfNeeded(LuceneDataSource.java:635)
at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.getIndexSearcher(LuceneDataSource.java:577)
at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.query(LuceneIndex.java:293)
at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex.get(LuceneIndex.java:229)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.index.UniqueFactory.getOrCreateWithOutcome(UniqueFactory.java:230)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.index.UniqueFactory.getOrCreate(UniqueFactory.java:216)
at com.ws.dao.NodeDaoImpl.createUniqueNode(NodeDaoImpl.java:71)
at com.ws.dao.NodeDaoImpl.createNode(NodeDaoImpl.java:34)
at com.ws.App.main(App.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

I have already increased the limit of # of open files in ulimit.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with Neo4j 2.1.1? If so, then please open an issue on Github, preferably with a minimal reproducing test case.

Comment: How do you insert the data? Can you share some more details / code?

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you changed your ulimit value, but not the right way to persist them for OSX.

Did you add values to /etc/launchd.conf ?

```
limit maxfiles 40000 40000
```

Comment: Yeah I did actually.I added the value and reboot the OS.Problem isn't resolved.

Comment: Try `lsof | wc -l` to see how many files are actually open, also. If there are too many, hitting 40k, perhaps you have a file handle leak somewhere else. Coincidentally, this happened to me once while I was building a network application that was leaking connections (neo4j started failing randomly because there weren't enough file handles, caused by the other program pushing it over the limit).